# Retrieve rows grouped by hour with MySQL

Tags: mysql, time, group-by

I have a table containing access logs. I want to know how many accesses to resource_id '123' occured in each hour in a 24 hour day.

My first thought for retrieving this info is just looping through each hour and querying the table in each loop with something like... `and time like '$hour:%'`, given that the `time` field holds data in the format `15:47:55`.

Is there a way I can `group by` the hours and retrieve each hour and the number of rows within each hour in a single query?

Database is MySQL, language is PHP.

Comment: is the 'time' column in datetime format?

Comment: Please post database structure -- do you have a `DATETIME` for access time?

Comment: @Zenshai you bested me by 41 seconds :-)

Comment: the time column is data type TIME

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
SELECT HOUR(MyDatetimeColumn) AS h, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY h;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function [HOUR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) to get the hour out of the time. Then you should be able to group by that.